# Scrape a page with Javascript and then append a specific section to current page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scrape and then pull out a specific section (section-two) to append to my current page.

**Current page**

```
<div id="container">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
   url: "external.html",
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function(data) {
      var externalPage = data;
      $("#container").append(externalPage);
   }
});
</script>
```

**external.html**

```
<div class="section-one">
  <p>Content I don't want</p>
</div>
<div class="section-two">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Ideal Result**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="section-two">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far I have loaded the external page into a variable but I do not know how to filter out only the section I want to append. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation, specifically the section titles [Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/remove/ check it out.

Comment: @Jaromanda X this won't work because the pages are not from the same origin. I am scraping a page from a different domain.

Comment: fair enough - so the other domain allows you to scrape their page (CORS) right?

Answer (score 0):

To only append `.section-two`, you'll need this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "external.html",
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function(data) {
      var externalPage = $($.parseHTML($.trim(data)));
      $("#container").append(externalPage.find('.section-two'));
   }
});
```

[`$.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) (optional) will remove any newlines and spaces at the beginning and end that might be in `external.html`. [`$.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) will convert the HTML string to a set of DOM nodes (so that we can traverse it). The surrounding `$` will convert the DOM nodes to a jQuery object so that we can use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to filter out the descendant that we want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
        url:"template.html",
        dataType:'text',
        success:function(data){
            var parsedHTML=$.parseHTML($.trim(data));
            var arr= jQuery.grep(parsedHTML, function( node, index ) {
                if($(node).attr('class')=="section-two"){
                    return node;
                }
        });
        $("#container").append(arr[0]);
        }
    });
```